# Красивый эффект - плавающая надпись на Jquery

Tags: jquery, плагин, эффекты, мышь

В теме http://greatives.eu/themes/reload-classic/ заголовок плавает в зависимости от положения мыши. Подскажите, с помощью какого плагина это реализовано или кода?

Comment: @liseluha, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Это из области "параллакса". [Вот примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/4o5n9c4e/)

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        $('.first').css({
            left: -e.pageX / 10 + 100,
            top: -e.pageY / 10 + 100
        });
        $('.second').css({
            left: e.pageX / 50 + 200,
            top: e.pageY / 50 + 200
        });
    });
});
```